# Vagrant / Puphpet Install: can't convert Fixnum into String

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

Major irritations trying to spin up some dev vm's using Puphpet and Vagrant on various machines without success. Typically I would get this type of error:

```
 ==> default: Error: can't convert Fixnum into String at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-8ac76db09acda5ab8c14f0bf13c0e157/mysql/manifests/server/root_password.pp:10 on node packer-virtualbox-iso-1422588891.vagrantup.com
 ==> default: Wrapped exception:
 ==> default: can't convert Fixnum into String
 ==> default: Error: can't convert Fixnum into String at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-8ac76db09acda5ab8c14f0bf13c0e157/mysql/manifests/server/root_password.pp:10 on node packer-virtualbox-iso-1422588891.vagrantup.com
 The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
 assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
 should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
 went wrong.
```

I searched and cannot find anything on either project's site or support groups.

Answer (score 0):

A little digging later and I have resolved the issue and post it here to save you tearing all of your hair out.

It seems that passwords in the **/puphpet/config.yaml** file are not all quoted. They need to be quoted.

eg.

```
root_password: 123
```

Will fail with an error, change to:

```
root_password: '123'
```

Note:

Search the entire config.yaml for occurrences of your passwords to check for quoting, it will likely be in more than one spot.

Will not. I had actually changed my password to something mixed alpha/numeric and still got problems.